# BigQuery error: "Cannot set write disposition in jobs with DML statements"

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-delete

I am trying to delete data from BQ table, and statement which worked yesterday stopped working today with the error:

```
delete from `project.my_dataset.my_table` where my_id='value'

Cannot set write disposition in jobs with DML statements
```

Comment: in UI - goto MORE >> QueryOptions and make sure you DO NOT have `Set a destination table for query results` option selected!